# Is it possible to manage the top navigation bar using SharePoint web services?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to remotely add links to the site top navigation bar. It is necessary for me to use SharePoint web services. I was able to create a sub site using the websvcMeetings, but there are no links in the top navigation bar. It should inherit parent's top nav bar and the parent's top nav bar should have the link to that newly created site.

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer - No. Sorry.

I had to write a simple Web service interface to do all the navigation mngt for Top and Quick Launch.

Comment: Although another option is to staple a custom feature and configure the navigation throught the object model.

Comment: Crap.. Custom Web services are not an option for my case. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you can build your own site definitions then it can be done? can u build deploy solutions?

Comment: As the things stand right now, I can upload my custom site template and create a sub-site based on that template. Accessing the server machine or central administration web site is denied. The only thing I am allowed to use is SharePoint web services and the rest of the C# API. I think I am stuck here, unfortunately. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, if u can build a site template then you can set the navigation flag through the ONET dot XML. Check out this blog for help on this : http://blogs.msdn.com/vesku/archive/2007/03/23/controlling-navigation-options-from-the-onet-xml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like DJ said: The only way to do this is to write your own web service, that then uses the SharePoint object model to create the site / change the navigation.

When you say you need to use web services, does that mean you can't are not allowed to deploy dll's (in sharepoint solutions)? If so, then the only way would be to do the navigation change by hand after creating the site.

Comment: Yeah, no web service dll deployments. I'm stuck with the manual setting. Thanks for your anwser.