# web service of sharepoint to get navigation

Tags: sharepoint, service, navigation, web

i have to use **sharepoint** web service strictly. And my task is get **Top navigation bar** and **Quick launch** of a site and its sub site. Does **sharepoint** provide **web service** to access top navigation bar and quick launch?

Comment: This is not possible - duplicate question of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432058/is-it-possible-to-manage-the-top-navigation-bar-using-sharepoint-web-services